# Concurrent modification exception for list

Tags: android, foreach, arraylist, hashmap

Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong here?

```
  File promoCountFile = new File(RaconTours.PATH + "promocodeCount.txt");
            if (promoPlistPath.exists()) {
                try {
                    ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(promoPlistPath));
                    ObjectInputStream promoStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(promoCountFile));
                    promoobj = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>) promoStream.readObject();
                    obj = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>) inStream.readObject();
                    for (HashMap<String, Object> tmpObj : obj) {
                        promoTourname = (String) tmpObj.get("promoTour");
                        promocodeID = (String) tmpObj.get("promocode");
                        if (promoTourname.equals(currentTour.getObjtourName())) {
                            //if the condition is met, remove the entry from the file
                            for (HashMap<String, Object> promoTemp : promoobj) {
                                promoTourCount =  (Integer) promoTemp.get("promocodeTourCount");
                            }

                            obj.remove(tmpObj);
                            --promoTourCount; 

                            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(promoPlistPath)); 
                            out.writeObject(obj);
                            out.close();

                            ObjectOutputStream promoout = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(promoCountFile)); 
                            HashMap<String, Object> promoCountDict = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                            promoobj.remove(0);
                            promoCountDict.put("promocodeTourCount",promoTourCount);
                            promoobj.add(promoCountDict);
                            promoout.writeObject(promoobj);
                            promoout.close();


                        }
                    }


                    if (obj.size() == 0 || promoTourCount == 0) {
                        promoPlistPath.delete();
                        promoCountFile.delete();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

Here it is giving me concurrent modification exception while the for loop iterates for the 2nd time or after that.

I am trying to update the value of promoTourCount in file each time as the loop iterates. But I am failing to do it. Because to avoid adding up multiple objects I am removing the object present at position 0 and adding the new one to that position( **promoobj.remove(0);**)

Plz help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying the collection you are iterating on. This will trigger an error. You iterate over obj here:

```
for (HashMap<String, Object> tmpObj : obj) {
```

But remove from it here:

```
obj.remove(tmpObj);
```

I recommend you to store the items to remove in another collection and remove them from the map only when you finish the for loop.

**Edit**: << *Adding example code* >>

```
List<Integer> toRemove = new LinkedList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < obj.size(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, Object> tmpObj = obj.get(i);

    if (/* something */) {
        /* ... */
        /* obj.remove(tmpObj);  replaced with*/
        toRemove.add(0, i); // notice that I add bigger indices first
    }
}
// Here we make the removal from bigger indices to smaller ones
// Notice that we iterate and remove from different collections.
for (Integer indexToDelete : toRemove) {
    obj.remove(indexToDelete);
}
```

This is the basic idea when you want to remove elements. However you need to output obj as modified immediately in the for loop. Then probably a bit of hacks with the indices will do better job for you:

```
for (int i = 0; i < obj.size(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, Object> tmpObj = obj.get(i);

    if (/* something */) {
        /* ... */
        /* obj.remove(tmpObj);  replaced with*/
        obj.remove(i); // We erase the element but this time we do not use enhanced for loop which is ok.
        i--; // we decrease the index because th enumber of elements decreased. Index hack. Ugly.
        System.out.println(obj); // modified obj :)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not getting it clearly, learning lists now. If you don't mind, could you please show me how to do it so that I won have this problem for the next time? But is it not the problem of 2nd for loop?

Comment: Well you have not shared the error itself if I am not wrong, with it it will be easier fro me to be certain. Still I think the second for loop is fine, it just queries the values... I will be editing my answer including some examplary code.

Comment: Well, the error is just Concurrent modification exception. Nothing else. I suspect even second for loop also should have problem in that case. Because even there I am updating the value,  promoobj.remove(0); The scenario goes like this, say initially I have value for promocodeTour as 2 and the loop goes, it decrements to 1 and checks for if condition after that first for loop. Now when it comes for one iteration, it becomes 0 and now it is catching the exception instead of coming to if

Comment: It would be really helpful for me if you could edit my code itself because I have no one here to ask my doubt :(

Comment: Actually I already did in a sense, just omitted the unchanged lines. You need to substitute the two lines outlined before the edit with the code from the second example code. You use the first two lines to substitute the for loop and the two lines immediately above the system.out to replace the remove I outlined and everything should be ok. Answer back if you see any further problems.

Comment: I am getting Indexout of bound in this case

Comment: Can you check where exactly you get this index out of bounds? It might be happening here  promoobj.remove(0); if you have empty list.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6312/discussion-between-tejas-and-boris-strandjev)